# Connecting two classes

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm stuck on this one exercise where I should create a second class called Car, that is linked to Vehicle. This is how it should look:

[image: https://gyazo.com/4c0c5c29fb7dec32080f3ce59383c320]

The vehicle class along with the testprogram works great, but now I want to connect the class Car to the vehicle, and then create a testclass for car. This is my vehicle class:

```
public class Vehicle {
int speed;

// Constructor
public Vehicle() {
    this.speed = 0;

}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    String regnr;

    public Car(String regnr) {
        this.regnr = regnr;
    }

    public String getRegNbr() {
        return this.regnr;
    }

}

public void increaseSpeed(int differenceInc) {
    int currentSpeed = this.speed;
    // Kör loopen så länge den nuvarande hastigheten inte är lika med den önskade
    while (this.speed != (currentSpeed + differenceInc)) {
        this.speed += 1;

        System.out.println("The current speed is increasing to: " + this.speed);
    }

}

public void decreaseSpeed(int differenceDec) {
    int currentSpeed = this.speed;

    while (this.speed != (currentSpeed - differenceDec)) {
        this.speed -= 1;
        System.out.println("The current speed is decreasing to: " + this.speed);
    }

}

public void brake() {
    int currentSpeed = this.speed;
    while (this.speed != 0) {
        this.speed /= 2;
        System.out.println("The current speed is decreasing to: " + this.speed);
    }
}

public int getSpeed() {
    return this.speed;
}

public void testVehicle() {

    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (this.speed != 0) {
        System.out.println("You're driving at: " + " " + this.speed + "KM/H" + "\n\nDo you want to:"
                + "\n(1) Slow down to " + "lower speed??" + "\n(2) Maintain current speed?"
                + "\n(3) Hit the brakes?" + "\n(4) Accelerate even more?");

        int choice = myScanner.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.print("By how much would you like to decrease your speed? ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int dec = in.nextInt();
            this.decreaseSpeed(dec);
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            System.out.println("Maintaining current speed");
        } else if (choice == 3) {
            System.out.println("Breaking!");
            this.brake();
        }

        else if (choice == 4) {
            System.out.print("By how much would you like to increase your speed? (km/h)");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int inc = in.nextInt();
            this.increaseSpeed(inc);
        }

        else {
            System.err.println("Incorrect value entererd.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    if (this.getSpeed() == 0)

    {
        System.out.println("Bilen står still");
    }

}
```

}

As you can see, the testVehicle() class along with a small separate test-program called VehicleTest runs the Vehicle class I created. I've added the Car-class to the program, and it extends vehicle as it should. The only question I have is how do I implement it into the test class?

My current separate test-program looks like this:

```
public class VehicleTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vehicle bmw = new Vehicle();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How fast do you want to drive?");

    int fast = scan.nextInt();
    bmw.increaseSpeed(fast);
    bmw.testVehicle();
}
```

}

Comment: Do you know inheritance in Java? If not, check https://www.javatpoint.com/inheritance-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive your Car1 class from Vehicle class

```
 public class Car1 extends Vehicle{

    String regnr;

    public Car1(String regnr) {
        super();//pass data to parent constructor if needed
        this.regnr = regnr;
    }

    public String getRegNbr() {
        return regnr;
    }

}
```

Now you will be able to call public methods from Vehicle class.

```
Car1 car = new Car1("DHM1234");
car.increaseSpeed(5); // The current speed is increasing to: 5
```

if you want to change behavior of any public/protected methods of your vehicle (parent) class for your car class, override that method
i.e

```
@Override
public void brake() {
    int currentSpeed = 0;
    System.out.println("Hard break");
}
```

now if you call `brake()` from car object

```
car.brake(); // Hard break will be printed
```

Give [Java Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) a read to learn more.

Comment: I've edited my initial post so you can see where I'm at. The one thing I've got left is to create the test class, but I don't know where it should be? Should it be inside of the test-program I posted at the bottom, or should I add it to the testVehicle method inside of the Vehicle class?

Comment: You can do both. The way you did is fine too.

Comment: Okay, so let's say that I the program to say: Your registration number is(...) and then print out the rest of the program as it is right now. If i type in      
        Car1 car = new Car1("DHM1234"); below the Vehicle bmw = new Vehicle(); All I get is "Car cannot be resolved to type"

Comment: you are doing it wrong inside your vehicle class, your car class should be outside of the vehicle class. in a separate file would be better

Comment: What exactly am I doing wrong? Also, shouldn't I be able to just type Car1 car = new Car1("DHM1234") and remove the Vehicle bmw = new Vehicle(), since the car class inherits the vehicle class?

Comment: wait I'm linking you the snippet

Comment: Glad to know. Then check the answer as correct to close this post.

Answer (score 1):

You should extend Car from Vehicle. Try this:

```
public class Car1 extends Vehicle {
...
}
```

Thus you may use Car like a Vehicle.

Some info to read https://books.trinket.io/thinkjava2/chapter14.html